# Espresso is not waiting for keyboard to open

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I have an espresso test where my screen contains an `EditText` and a skip `Button` underneath. 
When I launch the activity the keyboard pops open, focuses on the `EditText` and overlaps the `Button`.
I now want to write a test for the skip button and assert what happens afterwards.

The issue is that espresso does not wait for the keyboard to open.
So what happens is

- Espresso is not waiting for keyboard and presses "skip"
- Keyboard slides open
- Assertion for something thats now underneath the keyboard fails

The code looks like this:

```
public void givenSkipped_whenConfirmed_thenMainActivityLaunched() {
  Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();// <- Not working as espresso seems to think it is not open yet
  skipPostcodeEntry.perform(click()); //<- Can click this as keyboard is not open yet.

  warningText.check(matches(withText(R.string.some_text)));

  confirmationButton.perform(click());//<- Fails as this is now overlapped by KB

  Assert.DoesSomething()
}
```

I found an issue where espresso was [not waiting for the keyboard to close](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/issues/5) but nothing about it not waiting for the keyboard to open.

Has anyone solved this issue?

**Edit**:

When you look into the `closeSoftKeyboard` method you can find a class called `CloseKeyboardAction`. You can see that it even logs when the keyboard is not recognised as open.

```
 Log.w(TAG, "Attempting to close soft keyboard, while it is not shown.");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment it seems that Espresso has no way of checking whether the keyboard is on screen! (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/FyjybyM0wGA)

As a workaround, what we do is to check the input field that should have focus and then close the keyboard. This prevents Espresso calling closeSoftKeyboard() before the keyboard is on screen...

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    EspressoExtensions.closeKeyboardOnFocused(fieldThatShouldHaveFocus);
    //Continue with normal test
}
```

Then add the EspressoExtensions to your project:

```
public class EspressoExtensions {
  /**
   * This can be used to close the keyboard on an input field when Android opens the keyboard and
   * selects the first input when launching a screen.
   * <p>
   * This is needed because at the moment Espresso does not wait for the keyboard to open
   */
  public static void closeKeyboardOnFocused(ViewInteraction viewInteraction) {
    viewInteraction.check(matches(hasFocus())).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps, until Espresso has a way to assert whether the keyboard is on screen